# how can I save a Pandas dataframe into a compressed csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, gzip

I load a very large csv file in a `gz` format in Pandas 0.18 using

`pd=pd.read_csv('myfile.gz')`

Without surprise, once the csv is unzipped and loaded into the RAM, it takes a lot of space. However, I still need to save my file after I perform my computations.

Can `to_csv` store my dataframe in a `gz` format? The only [related question I found on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033270/how-to-save-a-pandas-dataframe-in-gzipped-format-directly) is 3 year old...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the parameter `compression='gzip'`

[source](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Comment: When you directly upload to s3, the compression will fail

Comment: @ShivangiSingh So how to deal with that issue? Could you make it work for s3 bucket?

Comment: You can use tempfiles